# can superposition of energy waves create mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass-energy, superposition

Is it possible that all particle with some specific mass be treated as superposition of some type of energy wave(electromagnetic wave) with some special wave function psi(x,t)? If so, then what will be the equation of such wave functions?

Comment: Energy is already mass, no "superposition" required, see [mass–energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). And quantum particles are described by quantum fields of the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), which are quite a bit more complicated then wave functions. So the answer to that is no.